Excel VBA - getting error 50290 when clicking on the Formula Bar 'check mark' but not when I use the 'Enter' key,
The following code sets up .OnEntry on the active sheet to run macro DCCapture.  When I edit a cell and hit the enter key, it works and selects cell 4,4. However, when I edit a cell and use the Formula Bar 'check mark' (instead of the enter key), I get run-time error 50290 'Application-defined or object-defined error'.
The macro does nothing but select a cell. Here is the code:
Sub SetOnEntry()
   ActiveSheet.OnEntry = "DCCapture"
End Sub

Public Sub DCCapture()
  Cells(4, 4).Select
End Sub

I would like the macro to work with both the enter key and with the Formula Bar 'check mark'. I thought they were treated the same in the background, but it seems not. Any help would be really appreciated.

You can use Change event instead of OnEntry:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Cells(4, 4).Select
End Sub

or in case of different sheets you can use Workbook_SheetChange:
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Sh.Cells(4, 4).Select
End Sub


Thank you.  That's what I'll use.  I still wonder why using the check in the formula doesn't work the same as the Enter key though.

I don't know either. The OnEntry method is a very old method, currently it is no longer supported by Microsoft since event handling was introduced. In this case, using the check icon causes the application to enter a permanent state Application.Ready = False and I can't change this state. I suspect this is an application bug that has not been corrected.
